# Override defaults for foundation 4 joyride

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I'm using foundation 4 and trying to override default settings for 'modal' and 'expose' for joyride:

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

I have tried added a third parameter in this start call, tried added data-options to the html.  Is a simple way do this?

I would like all the steps to be modal like with a faded out background.  And would like to be able to control which elements are 'expose'

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer I found and I hope it helps someone else:

Foundation Initializer:

```
$(function(){ 
    $(document)
        .foundation()
        .foundation('joyride', {modal: true});
});
```

Then, when you want to load the joyride:

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

Comment: this just solved my problem, thanks man. the documentation for all their js components leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: no prob. Yeah it's not fun sometimes when you need to quickly put something together.

Comment: can we use joyride by referencing only foundation.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new syntax for Foundation 5:

```
            $(document).foundation({
              joyride: {
                post_step_callback : function () {
                var elementID = $(this).data('id');
                  alert(elementID);
                },
                post_ride_callback : function () {
                  alert('We done!');
                }
              }
             }).foundation('joyride', 'start');         });
```